# ¿Cómo puedo lograr imprimir lo siguiente?

Tags: python, python-3.8

Tengo el siguiente código:

```py
import math

def f(x):
    return(0.39894*math.exp((-0.5)*x**2))
    
    
def sumariemann(): #Por la derecha (inferior) para evitar sobreestimaciones,
    a = -3.09
    b = [-3.09,-3.08,-3.07,-3.06,-3.05,-3.04,-3.03,-3.02,-3.01,-3,-2.99,-2.98,-2.97,-2.96,-2.95,-2.94,-2.93,-2.92,-2.91,-2.9,-2.89,-2.88,-2.87,-2.86,-2.85,-2.84,...,3.09]
    n = int(input("¿En cuántos rectángulo dividirá la curva?: "))
    Dx = [(bb - a)/n for bb in b]

    A=[]
    for j,bb in enumerate(b):
        rp=0

        for i in range(1,n):
            rp += f(bb-Dx[j]*i)*Dx[j]
        A.append(rp)
    return (A)
```

Quisiera imprimir cada valor de "*b*" con el resultado correspondiente que da la función. He intentado con `for`, pero no me ha dado resultado lo que hago. Además, ¿Cómo podría redondear los resultados que me da la función a 4 decimales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías adjuntar el valor de `b` y el resultado de `f(x)` a la misma lista `A` y para redondear únicamente utilizas `round()`

```
A.append([bb, rp.round(decimals=4)])
```

**Nota adicional:** veo que `b` tiene todos los alores desde a hasta -a (Es decir de -3.09 hasta 3.09), podrías utilizar `arange()` de `numpy` para evitar escribir toda la lista

Ejemplo completo:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return(0.39894*math.exp((-0.5)*x**2))
    
    
def sumariemann(): #Por la derecha (inferior) para evitar sobreestimaciones,
    a = -3.09
    b = np.arange(a,-a+0.01, 0.01).round(decimals=4)
    #b = [-3.09,-3.08,-3.07,-3.06,-3.05,-3.04,-3.03,-3.02,-3.01,-3,-2.99,-2.98,-2.97,-2.96,-2.95,-2.94,-2.93,-2.92,-2.91,-2.9,-2.89,-2.88,-2.87,-2.86,-2.85,-2.84,...,3.09]
    n = int(input("¿En cuántos rectángulo dividirá la curva?: "))
    
    Dx = [((bb - a)/n) for bb in b]

    A=[]
    for j,bb in enumerate(b):
        rp=0

        for i in range(1,n):
            rp += f(bb-Dx[j]*i)*Dx[j]
        A.append([bb, rp.round(decimals=4)])
    return (A)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!